# Set up DNS to pass through unknown domains

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

I run a linux web server which runs a BIND DNS server, how would i set it up so that if i change my DNS on my home computer to my remotes server ip i could use it as my DNS so that i could add custom records for example to have my own .tld but also still have access to the rest of the internet through this server?

ok, i have done that, added 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4 in my forwards on my servers. Re started the server, but when i browse to a website where the dns is changed to my server it will not retrieve the external request. It also overloads the cpu up to the point to crashing the server :?

i'm running on a CentOS server on very fast internet connection, 1GB ram. BIND DNS and a LAMP stack.

for some reason when i set my mac internet connection dns servers to my dns server it can bring it down, i need to stop people from doing that.

Comment: can you post you named.conf and any zone files? also are there error in /var/log/messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setup forwarders to your ISP or lets say Google (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4), then bind will see if it can translate the address locally and if it cant it will pass it on to resolve it.

Have a look at http://www.ubuntugeek.com/dns-server-setup-using-bind-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: ok, i have done that, added 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4 in my forwards on my servers. Re started the server, but when i browse to a website where the dns is changed to my server it will not retrieve the external request. It also overloads the cpu up to the point to crashing the server :?